# Map Interface java

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am learning whether I can use `Map<K,V>` interface for a program I am trying to create. My program contains two big arrays, `String[] groceryProducts`and respective prices: `int[] prices`. 
I want to use `Map<K,V>`for these two arrays so to map the `groceryProduct[xxx]` to its corresponding `price[yyy]`. 
Do I understand correctly that I can use Map's parameters (K,V) to do so?
Can I do something:

`Map(prices[], groceryProducts[]);`

And then add all the products and prices for them to the map? Is this what those two parameters are for? 
I am fresh to programming and I am sorry if my question is too dumb:).

Side question: Will using Map for big data volume affect the performance? I assume it is still better than nested loop in this case, isn't it? Thanks!

Comment: You really don't want to use an array as a `Map` key. In fact, this sounds like a `String, Integer` where the key is a product name and the value is the price.

Comment: Unrelated: *"and respective prices"* Sounds like arrays of equal length, with name in one array and price in the other. Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it, i.e. create a `GroceryProduct` class with two fields (`name` and `price`), and then have one array of those. Do not use parallel arrays.

Comment: Is he trying to do something like (as in Python) `dict(zip(prices, grocery_products))`? And have a relation between `String` and `Integer` for the relevant item and price?

Comment: *Will using Map for big data volume affect the performance?* Yes, positively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Map for this; it will perform better than almost anything you can do with your two arrays.

The first of the two parameters is the 'key' to the entry in the map; each key must be unique. The second parameter is the value stored for that key. In the case of `Map<String, Integer>`, you have a string key and an integer value. In the case of a Java Map, these parameters define the type of the values that will be stored in the map.

If a key with a value is already stored in the map, and you execute a statement that stores a different value for that key, it overwrites the first one.

You would not declare them the way you have it, however. The most normal way would be:

```
Map<String, Float> priceMap = new HashMap<>();
```

After which you could load the map with statements like:

```
priceMap.put("bread", 3.00);
priceMap.put("eggs",  2.50);
```

etc.

Then, when you have a string variable `item` that has the name of the item for which you want a price, you could use the statement:

```
Float price = priceMap.get(item);
```

Someone else suggested an `Item` object, containing both the name of the item and its price. This is reasonable, and even better, in other circumstances. In most significant programming projects, your 'Item' would have more than one characteristic (color, manufacturer, etc.) and the idea of OO programming is to create a class to represent such an object and store all its characteristics together in that object. You might, in that case, have a `Map<String, Item>` to map to the entire item from its name (or some other String key), and then get the price from there.

(Edit: sorry, I used Float ins of Integer. Same principles apply, I was just thinking of a price that included fractions of US dollars because that's what I'm most familiar with. One might also consider using BigDecimal, with its better handling of fractional numbers with precision limits.)

Comment: thanks for the tips. I think I am starting to understand this.:)